# Sequence $t_1<t_2<t_3 <\dots$ such that for any integer $c$, the sequence $t_1+c,t_2+c,t_3+c, \dots$ contains only a finite number of primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Does there exist an infinite increasing sequence $t_1<t_2<t_3 <\dots$ of positive integers such that for any integer $c$, the sequence $$t_1+c,t_2+c,t_3+c, \dots$$ contains only a finite number of primes?

I have been trying to find a construction to satisfy this condition, but can't really figure this out. Initially I thought that something like $t_n=n!$ would work since this has lots of factors in each number, but a friend of mine told me that this does not work which I don't see why?

If there is a working construction for this I would appreciate the details on how to derive it.

Comment: Context please?

Comment: It's just a problem from a problem solving book about number theory. @Mike

Comment: If $c_1,c_2,\dots$ is an enumeration of the integers, and $p_1,p_2,\dots$ are the primes. Pick $t_n$ using Chinese remainder theorem so that $t_n\equiv -c_i\pmod{p_i}$ for $i=1,\dots,n.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\{p_i\}_{i = 1}^{\infty}$ be the sequence of prime numbers. That is, $p_1 = 2$, $p_2 = 3$, $p_3 = 5$, etc.

Choose $t_k$ such that $t_k \equiv -i \pmod{p_i}$ for every $i \le k$. It's possible due to the Chinese remainder theorem. For example, $t_1 = 1$, $t_2 = 7$, $t_3 = 37$, $t_4 = 157$.

For every positive integer $c$, the number $t_i + c$ is composite for all $i \ge c$ since $p_c \mid t_i + c$.

This construction works only for positive $c$. But it's not hard to make it work for all $c \in \mathbb{Z} $, since integers can be enumerated like this: $0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3, \ldots$

Comment: It may be helpful/easier for the reader, if in your answer, you were to replace the subscript $i$ with $c$ in the 2nd paragraph, and then in the 3rd paragraph rewrite "For every positive integer $c$, the number $t_k+c$ is composite for all $k \ge c$ since $p_c|t_k+c$. Nice answer +1